# Running a message loop in a thread

Tags: java, jna

I want to run a low level keyboard hook using JNA. I've adapted an example found within JNA contrib folder

```
private static HHOOK keyHook;
private static LowLevelKeyboardProc keyCallback;

public static void main(String[] args) {
   final User32 U32 = User32.INSTANCE;
   final Kernel32 K32 = Kernel32.INSTANCE;

   HMODULE module = K32.GetModuleHandle(null); 
   keyCallback = (int code, WPARAM wParam, KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT info) -> {
      if (code >= 0) {
         System.err.println("Key=" + info.vkCode);
         if (info.vkCode == 81) {
           U32.PostQuitMessage(0);
         }
      }
      long peer = Pointer.nativeValue(info.getPointer());
      return U32.CallNextHookEx(keyHook, code, wParam, new LPARAM(peer));
   };
   keyHook = U32.SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, keyCallback, module, 0);
   System.out.println("Hook installed, type anywhere, 'q' to quit");

   MSG msg = new MSG();
   while (U32.GetMessage(msg, null, 0, 0) > 0) {         
      U32.TranslateMessage(msg);
      U32.DispatchMessage(msg);               
   }
   U32.UnhookWindowsHookEx(keyHook);
}
```

This is working as expected. Now however, I want to run the message loop in a thread to avoid blocking my application. A naive approach would be

```
Executor thread = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
thread.execute(() -> {
   int result;
   MSG msg = new MSG();
   while ((result = U32.GetMessage(msg, null, 0, 0)) > 0) {         
      U32.TranslateMessage(msg);
      U32.DispatchMessage(msg);               
   }
   U32.UnhookWindowsHookEx(keyHook);
});
```

Sadly this is not working. The callback is no longer invoked and keyboard inputs on the system start lagging massively. How can I thread my message loop correctly? I suppose I need to find the thread id and pass it to `SetWindowsHookEx` instead of 0, but how to obtain that id?

Edit: I've tried a different approach by encapsulating the whole hook registering and message loop in one thread. The callback now works correctly, but `PostQuitMessage` does not seem to post the message to the correct queue and the thread cannot be stopped. `PostThreadMessage(0, User32.WM_QUIT, null, null)` does not work either in that case.

Comment: I don't have the JNA framework handy but calling the `SetWindowsHookEx` methods and such from a different thread than the one where you perform the hook sounds sketchy. Try running all of the callback code inside the `thread.execute` part.

Comment: Updated the question with this. It's noticeably better, but now PostQuitMessage does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution is actually already provided by the JNA Platform in [User32Util.MessageLoopThread](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/contrib/platform/src/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/User32Util.java)